# Exception: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, oracle11g, database-connection, odac

In our project we are using VS2012 and Back end as Oracle 11g. First I've installed Oracle 11g 64bit and then installed ODTwithODAC1120320_32bit in different path

.I have copied my tnsname.ora file to

> C:\ora64\product\11.2.0\client_1\Network\Admin
>   folder(ODTwithODAC1120320_32bit installed path).

If I try to connect through oracle SQL developer works perfectly.  If I try to connect through my c# program it throws exception like:

> "ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified"
>   please any one help me to resolve this issue.

[image]

Comment: What is your connection string? Do you use TNS?

Comment: @AdilMammadov no we using normal connection string not TNS

Comment: The problem can be because your connection string is not correct or you are using wrong oracle client

Comment: @AdilMammadov Problem in the connection string,I forgot to include TNS   dbname into my connection string thank you

Comment: I am glad that it is solved